# Python matrix inverse

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-inverse

I have a camera matrix `k` which I have computed. The value of `k` is:

```
[[  1.92160183e+08   0.00000000e+00   3.06056985e+02]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.92160183e+08   1.57709172e+02]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
```

Now, I have tried to find the inverse of `k` using numpy (using `np.linalg.inv(k)`). Let `k1` be the inverse of `k`.

Using numpy, the value of `k*k1` is:

```
[[  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -4.87462472e-04]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00  -1.29434633e-04]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
```

Now, I was expecting a perfect identity matrix but since the values which should be zero are very small, I decided to ignore the fact that the result was not a perfect identity matrix.

Now my problem: I have two other matrices `R` and `h`. `R` is an identity matrix (it is not always an identity matrix but assume so for the sake of simplicity). I need to perform `H1 = k*R*k1*h`. This should ideally assign the value of h to H1 (since `k*R*k1` should turn out to be identity).

My original h matrix:

```
 [[  1.71025842e+00  -7.51761942e-01   1.02803446e+02]
 [ -2.98552735e-16   1.39232576e-01   1.62792482e+02]
 [ -1.13518150e-18  -2.27094753e-03   1.00000000e+00]]
```

My R matrix:

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1. -0.]
 [-0.  0.  1.]]
```

The value of `H1` produced using `H1 = k*R*k1*h`:

```
[[ 1.71025842 -0.         -0.        ]
 [-0.          0.13923258  0.        ]
 [ 0.         -0.          1.        ]]
```

The value of `H1` produced using `H1 = k*k1*h`:

```
[[ 1.71025842 -0.         -0.05011282]
 [-0.          0.13923258 -0.02107099]
 [-0.         -0.          1.        ]]
```

Why is the value of `H1` not coming equal to `h` as it should? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding on what the `*` operator does is flawed. It does not perform a dot product. But instead performs an *elementwise multiplication* on the two arrays, also known as the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).

So, if you have two 2D arrays, `A` and `B`, the dot product is computed with -

[image]

Whereas, the hadamard product looks like this -

[image]

Which is an elementwise multiplication (and what you're currently doing). Try replacing this with a call to `np.ndarray.dot` or using the `@` operator:

```
>>> k.dot(k1)
```

Or,

```
>>> k @ k1   # python3.5+
```

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Contrast this with -

```
>>> k * k1  
array([[  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,  -4.87462473e-04],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,  -1.29434634e-04],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00]])
```

Which is what you were getting earlier.

Comment: *matrices* by definition are 2D. So, it's redundant to use the term *2D matrices*. Either say 2D array or just matrices :)